# Windows application that compare two similar pictures and find the difference

Tags: windows, images, computer-vision

You know the spot the difference puzzles. Is there a app that can do that automatically?

Comment: Do you just want different *pixels* flagged, or do you want software that lets you define what counts as a difference? What price? What input formats? Any output required, or display-only? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 4):

There is an example of using [python](http://python.org) to do this visually for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341754/color-in-red-diffrencies-between-two-pictures/18342075#18342075) but to reproduce it:

- Done on windows - Yes but could be on any of a number of platforms
- Free

The code:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops

a = Image.open("pict1.jpg")
b = Image.open("pict2.jpg")
diff = ImageChops.difference (a, b)
RED = ('red')
RL = Image.new('RGB', diff.size, RED) # Make a red layer the same size
RedDiff = ImageChops.multiply(RL, diff)
Result = ImageChops.blend(RedDiff, b, 0.7)
Result.show()
```

### Example:

Inputs: [image]
Output:[image]